# C#: what is None keyword in class methods

Tags: c#

I'm only learning C# so I do not know a lot yet, but in this case  I can't find good answer in net.

I have such a class:

```
  public class CurrencyDetails : Value<CurrencyDetails>
    {
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public bool InUse { get; set; }
        public int DecimalPlaces { get; set; }


        public static CurrencyDetails None = new CurrencyDetails { InUse = false };
    }
```

and I do not understand what does this method doing `public static CurrencyDetails None = new CurrencyDetails { InUse = false };` and what is the `None` here???

Comment: Its the fields name. Its not a method.

Comment: @tkausl no, it is not.

Comment: Just the name of a static field, that is initialized

Comment: `None` is a name of [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) on `CurrencyDetails`. I would assume it is used to provide some "default" value. Also i would say it makes sense to make it `readonly`.

Comment: thanks, now I understand that it's a property... It just weird for me, not accustomed yet

Comment: @BogdanDubyk it's a field, not the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `None` is a static field under the `CurrencyDetails` type, that is also of type `CurrencyDetails`.

This is probably so that you can use `CurrencyDetails.None` as a variable where appropriate, which is arguably cleaner and easier to refactor than using `new CurrencyDetails { InUse = false }`.

It is a common pattern in .NET to expose static default/common values on the same type, for example `CancellationToken.None`.  Typically however they would be readonly, whereas the example you have posted is not.

Comment: thanks, now I understand that it's a property... It just weird for me, not accustomed yet

Comment: @BogdanDubyk It’s a field, not a property. It would be a property if instead of = the => symbol would have been used.